# Why does using conditional operator ? : causes returning local temporary object?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I run into a problem where using the conditional operator returns garbage string_view in MSVC, because the string_view was backed by a temp object?.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string hello("Hello");
char world[6] = { "World" };

std::string_view ChooseString( bool first )
{
    // warning: returning address of local temporary object
    return first ? hello : world; // returned string_view is garbage
    
    // all other ways of returning string_view works fine
    /*if ( first )
        return hello;
    else
        return world;*/
    //return first ? std::string_view( hello ) : std::string_view( world );
    //return hello;
    //return world;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ChooseString(true) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ChooseString(false) << std::endl;
}
```

Then I tried clang and gcc on goldbot, they had the same behavior, where clang gave warning: returning address of local temporary object. Also just returning hello or world were fine too. Can someone explain why the first way returns temporary object?

Is it because a string object is constructed after conditional operator is evaluated?

Comment: At a guess: Both arguments to `?` must be converted to the same type, and it's the first argument that determines the type. You're producing a temporary `std::string` for `world` and returning a `string_view` into it.

Comment: @user229044, but why didn't the compiler  create a temp `string_view` instead, since the return type is `string_view`?

Comment: Because the type of `first ? hello : world` is determined by the types of `hello` and `world`, not by the way the expression is used after it's evaluated.

Comment: The ternary operator requires that both possible results have the same type. If one type is convertible to the other, an implicit conversion is done. In your case, `hello` is of type `std::string` and `world` is an array of `char`, so `first ? hello : world` converts `world` to a (temporary) `std::string` and the ternary operator produces a `std::string` that is *then* converted to `std::string_view`.  You either need to prevent that conversion (e.g. in your commented `if`/`else` code) or avoid creating the temporary (e.g. by explicitly converting both strings to `std::string_view`).

Comment: You can just return `std::string`, in which case your temporary will be copied.

Comment: More generally, the type that results from ANY expression involving operators is determined *only* by its  operands.   It is not determined by how the result of that expression is subsequently used.

Comment: @Peter — there is one situation where the type of an expression is determined by how it’s used: when you take the address of an overloaded function, the type of the expression (hence the version of the function that’s selected) is determined by how it’s used.

Comment: @TonyJ *"since the return type is `string_view`?"* -- You've fallen into the trap of looking ahead. This is the same trap that (fairly commonly) leads people to write something like `float half = 1/2;` and receive the surprise that `half` is `0.0` -- first evaluate what you can (e.g. integer division or the ternary operator) *then* look at the destination. Same principle.

Comment: @PeteBecker   Thanks for that correction - it didn't occur to me when writing the previous comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the return type of condition operator is the common type of the operands. Given `first ? hello : world;`, i.e. the types of operands are `std::string` and `const char[]`, the common type will be `std::string`. A temporary `std::string` needs to be constructed for `world` then the temporary is used to construct the `std::string_view` which is returned later.

On the other hand for `first ? std::string_view( hello ) : std::string_view( world )` the return type is `std::string_view`, and all `std::string_view`s are constructed from `hello` and `world` directly, then no trouble as above.

Comment: I get garbage from `hello` too when `first` is true, does that mean a temp copy for `hello` was created as well? And why doesn't the compiler deduce `string_view` as common type?

Comment: @TonyJ, I guess as implementation there's always an `std::string` to be returned, either constructed from `hello` or `world`.

Comment: @TonyJ The compiler doesn't do that because that's not C++. The way an expression is used doesn't determine the type of the expression, ever. The result is the result, and it's converted to some other type after it's produced, but the way the result will be used cannot influence how the expression is evaluated. If that worked, you could overrload functions based only on their return type; you can't, because that's not how C++ works.

Comment: @TonyJ About return type, compiler finds `const char[]` can be converted to `std::string` then `std::string` is deduced as the common type. It won't check further more. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) for more details.

Comment: `string_view` is not a common type of either `std::string` or `const char[6]`.   To produce the result of `first ? hello : world`, the operands are converted at most once.   So to produce a `std::string_view` directly, it would need to convert `world` to `std::string` (the common type) and then convert the `std::string` to `std::string_view`, which is not allowed.   So `first ? hello : world` produces a `std::string` (from one operand or the other)  and that `std::string` is converted to `std::string_view` in order to `return`.

Comment: @user229044 — never say never. When you take the address of an overloaded function it’s disambiguated by how it’s used. After `void f(); void f(int)`, for example, `(void(*)())f` selects the first, and `(void(*)(int))f` selects the second. That is, the type of the expression `f` is determined by the cast. Sigh. Yes, that’s a distraction here.